# What's the chance that I'll win a door prize?

Tags: code-golf, math, probability-theory

My local ACM chapter gives out door prizes to people who come to the meetings. You get an increased chance of winning if you solve the programming puzzle, however (but *I* always solve that puzzle). Thus, some people have 1 entry, while others have 2. But wait! The way the raffle program works is not by adding in another entry when someone solves the puzzle. Instead, it keeps track of the number of "lives" a person has, decrementing that if that person is chosen in each pass of it's random sampling algorithm. So it works like this:

```
Doorknob: 1.  xnor: 2.  Justin: 2.  Alex: 1.  Dennis: 2.
```

Then the program randomly chooses one of `[Doorknob, xnor, Justin, Alex, Dennis]`, decrements the number (say it chooses `Justin`):

```
Doorknob: 1.  xnor: 2.  Justin: 1.  Alex: 1. Dennis: 2.
```

And repeats. If someone's number of "lives" goes to `0` (let's choose `Justin` again), they're removed from the list:

```
Doorknob: 1.  xnor: 2.  Alex: 1.  Dennis: 2.
```

This continues until there's one person left; that person is the winner.

Now the real question is, what was the probability that I would have won?

---

You will be given two inputs:

- `n`. This is the number of people entered into the challenge
- `k`. This is the number of people (of those `n`) who have 2 lives. This number always includes you.

So if I had a function `p` and called `p(10, 5)`, that would be the probability of winning the prize where there are 10 people total, 5 of which only have 1 life, whereas 5 (including you) have 2 lives.

---

You are expected to output the probability of winning either exactly, or as a decimal. At any rate, answers must be accurate up to and including the 4<sup>th</sup> decimal place after the decimal point. Whether or not you round to that digit is up to you.

Your solution may be a randomized solution which outputs the answer to the 4<sup>th</sup> decimal place with *high probability*. You may assume that the built in RNG you use is truly random, and it must output the correct answer with at least 90% probability.

Furthermore, your code need only work for `n, k <= 1000`, although I did provide test cases larger than that for those curious.

---

### Test Cases

Note: some of these are general formulae.

```
n,    k   |  output
----------+---------
1,    1   |  1
2,    2   |  0.5
2,    1   |  0.75
3,    1   |  11/18 = 0.611111111
1000, 1   |  0.007485470860550352
4,    3   |  0.3052662037037037
k,    k   |  1/k
n,    1   |  (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[1 + n])/n    (* Mathematica code *)
          |  (γ + ψ(1 + n))/n
10,   6   |  0.14424629234373537
300,  100 |  0.007871966408910648
500,  200 |  0.004218184180294532
1000, 500 |  0.0018008560286627948
---------------------------------- Extra (not needed to be a valid answer)
5000, 601 |  0.0009518052922680399
5000, 901 |  0.0007632938197806958
```

For another few checks, take `p(n, 1) * n` as follows:

```
n     |  output
------+---------
1     | 1
2     | 1.5 
3     | 1.8333333333333335
10    | 2.928968253968254
100   | 5.1873775176396215
-------------------------- Extra (not needed to be a valid answer)
100000| 12.090146129863305
```

Comment: I'm no longer familiar with the tags on this site; if you think of a more appropriate tag, please edit away!

Comment: Closely related question on math.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1669715/72616

Comment: So, P(n,k) = ((k-1)/n)P(n,k-1) + ((n-k)/n)P(n-1,k) + (1/n)Q(n,k-1), where Q(n,k) = ((n-k-1)/n)Q(n-1,k) + (k/n)Q(n,k-1) and Q(1,0)=1...

Comment: @KennyLau I'm not going to attempt to interpret it, but beware the math.se link, as it uses a slightly different definition of the function (I believe `k` is off by one)

Comment: Instead of `EulerGamma....` it would be clearer to write `H(n)/n` where H(n) = harmonic numbers.

Comment: Is it OK to do a randomized simulation with enough trials that the answer is correct to the fourth decimal place with high probability, though of course not certainty?

Comment: If only the lives were randomly chosen then the answer would be 2/(n+k)...

Comment: @xnor I think that should be reasonable

Comment: Rounding error in p(n,1)*n? "1.833333333335" shouldnt it be "1.8333333333333"

Comment: @BlockCoder1392 I didn't worry about that because it's past the 4th decimal place. But yes, you are right

Comment: This question is for a challenge I think? Math.SE is not PPCG.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 42 bytes

```
:<~QXJx`J`tf1Zry0*1b(-tzq]f1=vts3e8<]6L)Ym
```

This uses a probabilistic (Monte Carlo ) approach. The experiment is run a large number of times, from which the probability is estimated. The number of realizations is selected to *ensure* that the result is correct up to the fourth decimal with probability at least 90%. However, this takes a very long time and a lot of memory. In the link below the number of realizations has been reduced by a factor of 10<sup>6</sup> so that the program ends in a reasonable amout of 
time; and only the *first* decimal is guaranteed to be accurate with at least 90% probability.

*EDIT (July 29, 2016): due to changes in the language, `6L` needs to be replaced by `3L`. The link below incorporates that modification.*

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Ojx-UVhKeGBKYHRmMVpyeTAqMWIoLXR6cV1mMT12dHMzZTI8XTNMKVlt&input=Mwox)

#### Background

Let *p* denote the probability to be computed. The experiment described in the challenge will be run for a number *n* of times. Each time, either you win the prize (“*success*”) or you don't. Let *N* be the number of successes. The desired probability can be *estimated* from *N* and *n*. The larger *n* is, the more accurate the estimation will be. The key question is how to select *n* to fulfill to the desired accuracy, namely, to assure that at least 90% of times the error will be less than 10<sup>−4</sup>.

Monte Carlo methods can be

- *Fixed-size*: a value of *n* is fixed in advance (and then *N* is random);
- *Variable-size*: *n* is determined on the fly by the simulation results.

Among the second category, a common used method is to fix *N* (desired number of successes) and *keep simulating until that number of successes is achieved*. Thus *n* is random. This technique, called *inverse binomial sampling* or *negative-binomial Monte Carlo*, has the advantage that the accuracy of the estimator can be bounded. For this reason it will be used here.

Specifically, with negative-binomial Monte Carlo *x* = (*N*−1)/(*n*−1) is an unbiased estimator of *p*; and the probability that *x* deviates from *p* by more than a given ratio can be upper-bounded. According to equation (1) in [this paper](http://oa.upm.es/4350/2/MENDO_ART_2008_01.pdf) (note also that the conditions (2) are satisfied), taking *N* = 2.75·10<sup>8</sup> or larger ensures that *p*/*x* belongs to the interval [1.0001, 0.9999] with at least 90% probability. In particular, this implies that *x* is correct up to the 4th decimal place with at least 90% probability, as desired.

#### Code explained

The code uses *N* = `3e8` to save one byte. Note that doing this many simulations would take a long time. The code in the link uses *N* = `300`, which runs in a more reasonable amount of time (less than 1 minute in the online compiler for the first test cases); but this only assures that the *first* decimal is correct with probability at least 90%.

```
:        % Take k implicitly. Range [1 ... k]
<~       % Take n implicitly. Determine if each element in the previous array is
         % less than or equal than n
Q        % Add 1. This gives an array [2 ... 2 1 ... 1]
XJx      % Copy to clipboard J. Delete from stack
`        % Do...while. Each iteration is a Monte Carlo realization, until the 
         % desired nunber of successes is reached
  J      %   Push previously computed array [2 ... 2 1 ... 1]
  `      %   Do...while. Each iteration picks one door and decrements it, until
         %   there is only one
    t    %     Duplicate
    f    %     Indices of non-zero elements of array
    1Zr  %     Choose one of them randomly with uniform distribution
    y0*  %     Copy of array with all values set to 0
    1b(  %     Assign 1 to chosen index
    -    %     Subtract
    tzq  %     Duplicate. Number of nonzero elements minus 1. This is falsy if
         %     there was only one nonzero value; in this case the loop is exited
  ]      %   End do...while
  f1=    %   Index of chosen door. True if it was 1 (success), 0 otherwise
  v      %   Concatenate vertically to results from previous realizations
  ts3e8< %   Duplicate. Is the sum less than 3e8? If so, the loop is exited
]        % End do...while
6L)      % Remove last value (which is always 1)
Ym       % Compute mean. This gives (N-1)/(n-1). Implicitly display
```

Comment: Haha I didn't realize that 90% would make it that difficult :-)

Comment: Yes, _fourth_ decimal with 90% confidence is a really strong requirement :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 34 bytes

```
Mc|!*HJ-GHch*J+*tHgGtH*gtGHKh-GHKG
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Mc%7C%21%2aH-GH%2Bch%2a%2a-GHtHgGtHh-GH%2a-GHgtGHGgEE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A1%0A2%0A2%0A2%0A1%0A3%0A1%0A1000%0A1%0A4%0A3%0A10%0A6%0A300%0A100%0A500%0A200&input_size=2)

Defines a deterministic memoized recursive function `g` taking *n*, *k* as arguments.  `g 1000 500` returns `0.0018008560286627952` in about 18 seconds (not included in the above test suite because it times out the online interpreter).

An approximate Python 3 translation would be

```py
@memoized
def g(n,k):
    return (not k*(n-k) or (1+(n-k)*((k-1)*g(n,k-1)+g(n-1,k)*(n-k+1)))/(n-k+1))/n
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 65 bytes

```
f=(n,k,d=n-k)=>(!d||(f(n-1,k)*++d*--d+1+(--k&&f(n,k)*k*d))/++d)/n
```

Don't try it with the big numbers though; even f(30, 10) takes a noticeable amount of time.